# Is there a program that gives an ideal in the ring of integers that is not principal and coprime to $23N$ for $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, sagemath

Consider the quadratic number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$. Is there a program in sage that gives an ideal in the ring of integers that is not principal and coprime to $23N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$? So far I have

```
sage: K.<a> = QuadraticField(-23)
sage: K.ideals_of_bdd_norm(5)
```

which gives me all ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ up to norm $5$.

Comment: I haven't learned Sage (I probably should sooner rather than later), but presumably it has a command calculating the class group. I would hazard a guess that, upon request, it will also list ideals representing the various classes. I would not be surprised if the representative are chosen to have minimal norms also. Anyway, I would look for such commands in the documentation.

Comment: There is an isomorphism from the form class group of positive binary quadratic forms, in this case reduced representatives are $x^2 + xy + 6 y^2,$ $2x^2 +xy+3y^2,$ $2x^2 - xy + 3y^2.$ There is now a book for beginners by Lehman that follows quadratic forms and quadratic number fields side by side through the whole book. https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/

Comment: Meanwhile, Cohen A Course in Computationla Algebraic Number Theory has a section 5.2 called Ideals and Quadratic Forms which displays the mappings. Pages 225-230.