# solving congruences with sage

Tags: number-theory, sagemath

Let $\mathfrak{p}=(\pi_1)$ be a prime ideal in  $\mathcal{O}_K$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$. Is there any code in sage that  solves the congruence $\pi_1 \equiv 1 (\text{mod}\sqrt{-23}N)$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708480/is-there-a-program-that-gives-an-ideal-in-the-ring-of-integers-that-is-not-princ).

Comment: What is explicitly given (best with an example) and which element(s) in $\mathcal O_K$ are needed?

Comment: You may want to try asking this as ask.sagemath.org as well